# Randomly change div gradient backgrounds on load

Tags: javascript, css, linear-gradients

So what I'd like to do is have a few divs with the same class name change gradient background on load. I've managed to get this far but with colors. How do I get it to change gradients?
So in place of 'red' I'd like something like `linear-gradient(to right, #1565C0, #b92b27)`

```
let colors = [
    'red',
    'blue',
    'green',
    'teal', 
    'tan',
    'plum'
];
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".cardGradient");

for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let colors = [
    ['red', 'blue'],
    ['green', 'teal'],
    ['tan', 'plum']
];
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".cardGradient");

for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    colorIndex = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

    boxes[i].style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, '+colorIndex[0]+', '+colorIndex[1]+')';
}
```

```css
.cardGradient {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardGradient"></div>
```

Comment: @HookedHangman then accept this answer as solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the same logic as you did for solid color backgrounds, this can be achieved in similar way :-

```js
let colors1 = [
    'red',
    'blue',
    'green',
    'teal', 
    'tan',
    'plum'
];

let colors2 = [
    'red',
    'blue',
    'green',
    'teal', 
    'tan',
    'plum'
];
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".cardGradient");

for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to right, ${colors1[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors1.length)]}, ${colors2[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors2.length)]} )`;
}
```

```css
.cardGradient{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='cardGradient'></div>
<div class='cardGradient'></div>
<div class='cardGradient'></div>
<div class='cardGradient'></div>
<div class='cardGradient'></div>
<div class='cardGradient'></div>
```